# Property Placeholders in Micronaut for file mounts

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I am trying to provide secrets as property placeholders. For instance with mongobd uri, I want the username and password coming from secrets on a volume. Is this possible? For instance with the below kubernetes config, the placeholder I could provide was `${kubernetes.client.secrets.paths}`, but I needed access to the nested secrets from inside the "paths". Does the question make sense?

```
mongodb:
    uri: mongodb://${username}:${password}@localhost:27017/databaseName


kubernetes:
  client:
    secrets:
      enabled: true
      use-api: true
      excludes: mounted-secret
      paths:
        - /foo
        - /kvmnt
```